# Deneb highlight row of selected point in a matrix

Tags: vega-lite, deneb

I have created a matrix visual using Deneb. I am able to highlight the selected cell using the method described here [simple-encoding-of-opacity-with-conditions](https://deneb-viz.github.io/interactivity-selection#example-1-simple-encoding-of-opacity-with-conditions).

I would like to highlight the whole row, i.e. all the rows in the dataset that have the same field value as the selected item for the field on the axis ( the matrix row). But I am unable to build the expression.

My goal is to create a transform which would return "Y/N" for each row in the dataset when it has the value for the "parent" field as the row which has the "**selected**" field equal to "on" (Named "IsParentSelected" in the picture below.
[target transformed dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5Juz.png)

I would appreciate if someone could help with the transform expression.